# Resource compilation failed on updating material library to 1.1.0

Tags: android, androiddesignsupport, material-components

I have updated my material library from ***com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0*** to ***com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0***

I am getting the following error after the update. The only solution that I found is to revert it to an older version.

Also, I have tried updating every dependency to latest version, but that didn't work either.

> /home/name/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/03d95e2ec81bf572bcb58974acba7470/material-1.1.0-alpha06/res/values/values.xml:718:5-725:23:
>   AAPT: error: duplicate value for resource 'attr/checkedButton' with
>   config ''.

adding my dependencies for reference:

```
 // Support libraries
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.1.0'

//Retrofit and ok http
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.5'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.1'

//Multidex
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'

// Flex
implementation 'com.hopenlib.library:cflextools:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0'

// Testing
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
```

Comment: try invalidating and restarting android studio

Comment: @Raghunandan Already tried it.

Comment: just try rebuilding with a clean build.

Comment: or even delete /home/name/.gradle/ and rebuilding would help.

Comment: @SunSun try remove // Flex
implementation 'com.hopenlib.library:cflextools:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android:flexbox:1.0.0', other libs r okay here

Comment: @Raghunandan I have already tried all those kinds of things.

Answer (score 0):

if you are getting AAPT issue than issue might be in your any of your XML file.
or if this not the issue please try to add

> `implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0''`

Comment: why u advising add support lib if he using androidX?

Comment: Sorry i didnt check he is using android X. he has to implement implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Answer (score 0):

IF you are getting AAPT issue in **androidx**  than issue might be in your any of your layout files if your project in androidx then you can update your design library.
**Also check all layout files any resource file and drawable file or sting files may be missing.**

> implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Comment: plz, can you check in the layout file if any checked button there? if it issues in that file.you can also shear code.

Comment: I don't understand what u r talking about

Comment: What "my" layout file r u talking about?) Check my nickname and question author name